# Scala flatten a map with list as key and string as value

Tags: scala, collections

I have a peculiar case where I want to declare simple configuration like so

```scala
val config = List((("a", "b", "c"), ("first")), 
               (("d", "e"), ("second")),
               (("f"), ("third")))
```

which at run time, I would like to have a map, which maps like

```
"a" -> "first"
"b" -> "first"
"c" -> "first"
"d" -> "second"
"e" -> "second"
"f" -> "third"
```

Using `toMap`, I was able to convert the `config` to a Map

```
scala> config.toMap
res42: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.io.Serializable,String] = Map((a,b,c) -> first, (d,e) -> second, f -> third)
```

But I am not able to figure out how to flatten the list of keys into keys so I get the final desirable form. How do I solve this?

Comment: That is not a simple configuration because you have tuples of different lengths inside each tuple (Note that the key type is `java.io.Serializable`).  If you use `List`s rather than tuples in the inner data it will be much easier.

Comment: You are right. Declaring the key as a list rather than tuples combined with the answer posted below, I was able to get my desired result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution below:

```
val config = List(
      (("a", "b", "c"), ("first")),
      (("d", "e"), ("second")),
      (("f"), ("third")))

val result = config.map {
  case (k,v) =>
    (
      k.toString().replace(")", "")
        .replace("(", "")
        .split(","), v)
  }

val res = result.map {
  case (key,value) => key.map{ data =>
    (data,value)
  }.toList
}.flatten.toMap
```

In case you change the config structure to something like below, solution is much more simpler:

```
val config1 = List (
  (List("a", "b", "c"), "first"),
  (List("d", "e"), "second"),
  (List("f"), "third")
)


config1.flatMap{
  case (k,v) => k.map{data => (data,v)}
}.toMap
```

Comment: In your second example, here: `case (k,v) => k.map{data => (data,v)}.toMap`, `toMap` doesn't actually change anything. You can safely remove that and save some cpu cycles.

Answer (score 2):

If you structure your `config` using `List` the code is very simple:

```
val config = List(
  (List("a", "b", "c"), ("first")),
  (List("d", "e"), ("second")),
  (List("f"), ("third")))

config.flatMap{ case (k, v) => k.map(_ -> v) }.toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the above answers are good practical answers. If you're in a situation where you have no control over the input and you're stuck with `Tuple`s instead of `List`s, I'd do it this way:

```scala
val result: Map[String, String] = config.flatMap { 
  case (s: String, v) => List(s -> v)
  case (ks: Product, v) => ks.productIterator.collect { case s: String => s -> v }
  case _ => Nil //Prevent throwing
}.toMap
```

This will throw away anything that's not a `String` in the keys.

Answer (score 0):

by using in built spark sql functions

```
val config = List((Array("a", "b", "c"), ("first")),
      (Array("d", "e"), ("second")),
      (Array("f"), ("third"))).toDF(List("col1","col2") : _*)

config.withColumn("exploded",functions.explode_outer($"col1")).drop("col1").show()
```